# Install MySQL Database driver for Superset inside a docker

Tags: docker, mysql-connector, apache-superset

I have installed [Superset](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html) using the docker method, but now I can't connect to my MySQL database because the driver can't be loaded.

I have tried installing it via `pip install mysqlclient`, and it is reported as successfully installed :

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for mysqlclient: filename=mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=108116 sha256=b05681e22caca22b405d0b518651bb8849df47e31f124571dd8788d585dd522f
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8a/3c/e6/347e293dbcd62352ee2806f68d624aae821bca7efe0070c963
Successfully built mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.4.6
```

I have restarted the docker, but the driver *still* can't be loaded inside Superset.

What needs to be done? How can I install the missing MySQL driver so the docker container can see it and use it?

Comment: if you have used python3 can you try with pip3  ?

Comment: I'm using `venv`, the same used to install Superset.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the `requirements.txt` file inside the installation directory, and added this line

```
mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

Then executed the command

```
docker-compose up --build
```

and now we're able to connect.