# adding driver to Superset docker image

Tags: docker, apache-superset, supertest

I am running Superset on k8s, as a helm chart, according to the docs, to install a driver you need to do add it here:

> bootstrapScript: |
> #!/bin/bash
> **pip install x**
> if [ ! -f ~/bootstrap ];
> then echo
> "Running Superset with uid {{ .Values.runAsUser }}" > ~/bootstrap; fi

but the issue is i am running this helm chart in an offline environment due to nonfunctional requirements we have

I tried to customize the docker image by the following

```
FROM apache/superset:master
RUN pip install clickhouse-connect==0.5.23
```

however the driver isn't present even after doing so, it seems that my way of installing the driver isn't correct

my question is how can i customize the superset docker image to include the drivers? all the resources/stackoverflow answers i found uses 'Docker Compose' [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963784/install-mysql-database-driver-for-superset-inside-a-docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to do the switch to the root user before the install and then switch back to superset when finished as shown below:

```
    FROM apache/superset:master
    USER root
    RUN pip install clickhouse-connect==0.5.23
    USER superset
```

Also, read more on the docker hub page https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset